# table apply css for row

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

I am working on html table where I need to add background color on rows but I don't have any class on the row. I am trying to use nth-child but I am not sure of my logic.

I want 2 rows to come in same background color and next 2 rows should come with background color2 like below image

[image]

```css
tr:nth-child(2n) td {
  background-color: yellow
}

tr:nth-child(2n+1) td {
  background-color: pink
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>background should come as color1</td></tr>
<tr><td>background should come as color1</td></tr>

<tr><td>background should come as color2</td></tr>
<tr><td>background should come as color2</td></tr>

<tr><td>background should come as color1</td></tr>
<tr><td>background should come as color1</td></tr>

<tr><td>background should come as color2</td></tr>
<tr><td>background should come as color2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Above is giving background color to alternate row

Comment: can you add what is that you want to achieve ?

Comment: You can probably drop the [tag:javascript] and [tag:jquery] tags as they don't relate to the question.  And including a [mcve] with your markup in a snippet would be helpful.

Comment: Added image please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
tr {
  background-color: yellow
}

tr:nth-child(4n),
tr:nth-child(4n - 1){
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<table>

<tr><td>//background should come as color1</td></tr>
<tr><td>//background should come as color1</td></tr>

<tr><td>//background should come as color2</td></tr>
<tr><td>//background should come as color2</td></tr>

<tr><td>//background should come as color1</td></tr>
<tr><td>//background should come as color1</td></tr>

<tr><td>//background should come as color2</td></tr>
<tr><td>//background should come as color2</td></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, for the `nth-child` use `(4n+1)`, `(4n+2)`, `(4n+3)` and `(4n+4)` (i.e. steps of four with an offset):

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table,
td {
  height: 20px;
}

tr:nth-child(4n+1) td,
tr:nth-child(4n+2) td {
  background-color: yellow
}

tr:nth-child(4n+3) td,
tr:nth-child(4n+4) td {
  background-color: red
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
Above solution works and first solution also works